# Django: How to display multiple products from cart in template

Tags: django, django-views, e-commerce, shopping-cart, django-class-based-views

How to display multiple products those are in cart into dashboard template. I have write CBV for particular Cart id but it doesn't display all product but displays only one the one added first to the cart. Even in admin only one product is displayed. I want to display all products in cart. So its easy to check what products customer has ordered.

views.py

```
class MyadminCartItemDetailView(DetailView):
    model = CartItem
    template_name = "mydashboard/cart/cartitem_detail.html"

def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
    context = super(MyadminCartItemDetailView,     self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
    return context
```

cartitem_detail.html

```
<table class="table table-hover">
  <thead>
    <tr> 
      <th>Cart ID</th>
      <th>Cart Items</th>
      <th>Baker Name</th>
      <th>Product Price</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>{{ object.cart }}</td>
      <td>{{ object.product }}</td>                      
      <td>{{ object.product.baker }}</td>   
      <td>{{ object.product.price }}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

models.py

```
class CartItem(models.Model):
    cart = models.ForeignKey('Cart', null=True, blank=True)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product)
    variations = models.ManyToManyField(Variation, null=True, blank=True)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    line_total = models.DecimalField(default=10.99, max_digits=1000, decimal_places=2)
    notes = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.product.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('cart_item_detail', kwargs={"id": self.id})


class Cart(models.Model):
    total = models.DecimalField(max_digits=100, decimal_places=2,  default=0.00)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "Cart id: %s" %(self.id)
```

I tried iterating "object.product", but it returned with error "object.product" is not iterable. And list view will display all cart items from model CartItem. Is there any way to do it?

Comment: Can you show the CartItem model?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not use DetailView here . Detai View is for particular single product. You cannot iterate over in Detail view for the product.

If you want to use multiple product then do query it in get_context_data and send context to template and iterate it there.

```
class MyadminCartItemDetailView(TemplateView):
    template_name = "mydashboard/cart/cartitem_detail.html"

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
    context = super(MyadminCartItemDetailView,     self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
    context['products'] = CartItem.objects.all()

    return context
```

and in your template use it like

```
{% for product in products %}
    {{product.id}}
    {{product.title}} # Fields related to product
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: How to a write a query for that. I am stuck at that part only.

Comment: You can use anyother view for that, try template view or anything relevant and in you get_context_data do query like context['product'] = Product.objects.all() and return the context